# About memory management in Objective-C or iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello every one this is my `first post` in this site and I am a newbie to iOS. I know that it's for programming site, but I don't have access to any iOS experts, resources to understand about my doubt, so please dont mark me as `negative`, try to solve my problem. Here is my question:

Some days ago I went for formal interview in our college for iOS interview, and they asked me:

1. `what is memory management in Objective-C or iOS?`

**i said:**  Memory mangement are used the retain count way in which memory is managed in Objective-C. When we create a object it has retain count of 1. When we send an object a retain message, its retain count is incrementedby 1. And when we send release message retain count is decreased by 1.

2. `what type of memory management are using like MRC/ ARC??`

**i said :**  For MRC it we alloc, retain it have to do release/autorelease for ARC we need to release / autorelease.

```
My question is:


1. Actually is my first answer correct about memory management?

2. From which version of iOS SDK are using ARC, MRC?
```

please kindly solve my confusion. It will help me to know what is what?

Thanks.

Comment: you can get some more understanding my answer here [memory management tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655204/ios-application-behaviour-in-case-of-low-memory/20657274#20657274)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC - Automatic Reference Counting was introduced since iOS4. And currently ARC is the most common and the best practice for iOS development.

MRC - Manual Reference Counting is where you have to DIY.

Memory Management - In iOS objects should be in memory or not, depends on the objects retain count.When you create an object the retain count is 1.
When you sent `retain` or `strong` message to the object the retain count is increased by 1 and when you sent `release` the retain count is decreased by 1. Finally when an objects retain count is 0, the memory for that object is released.

Now in ARC you dont have to worry about all these. You write your code and in compile time compiler puts these messages in places for you, which you dont get to see. PS-`release` is forbidden in ARC.

In MRC you have to keep track of all objects memory count yourself and that is a hassle so apple introduced ARC in the first place.

That is memory management in a Nutshell. 
For a better understanding please visit this [link](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/memory-management). This blog explains memory management in a more detailed way. 
Hope this helped you.

Comment: "ARC is a must for iOS" where do you take that from? I'd wouldn't object to "best practice", "common" or even "ubiquitous"—but it's not a requirement.

Comment: let me rephrase it,  MRC is obsolete which makes ARC the most common and best practice.  Thanks for pointing it out. Editing it

Comment: Thanks for your valuable and clear explaniation about my doubt.

Comment: @SahebRoy in interview if interviewer ask me what is memory management as i said my answer is correct in my post what i have mentioned

Comment: Hi Thanks for the explanation. The link you shared at the end is not working

Answer (score 0):

(1)For Memory Management, there is a good  Tutorial available here (http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/memory-management-tutorial-for-ios)

(2)In ARC, the OS looks after the memory management, so you don't have to worry about releasing the objects.It's pretty neat for beginners. Whereas in Manual counting you will have to keep track of releasing the memory and if you don't do it ,you will end up crashing your app.

ARC and MRC are available in ios whereas garbage collection is limited to MAC-OSX hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your explantation and for link.will look out it