# About CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have been looking out to learn about collection view in this [link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2014/11/23/making-gridview-ios-uicollectionview/) for a days. In this link it has `viewcontroller.h,.m`   and also `CustomCollectionCell.h,.m`.

1. Why are they creating separate class for that cell? We can use the `viewcontroller.m` file to manage our `cell` in collection view.
2. how ARC works (retain cycles, weak vs. strong, etc), threading (when to use background thread, when to use main).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi This is matter of choice to create separate class for collection View cell , you can also create the custom collection view cell class in .m file

dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath is method of UICollectionView same as in UITableView this methods just reuse the cells that are created, by this compile don't need to create a cell each time when you scroll or update data in collection view , this enable us to reuse the collectionView Cell.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. i edited my post with second question. can you explain me about my second question in my poat.it will be very useful

Comment: ARC is vey good feature now , this removes the extra burden of retaining the object , release . Without ARC we have to manually claim the ownership of any object that we create, release the object when we are done with it otherwise this creates memory leaks but now ARC do this, ARC Automatically releases the object when we are done with it. you can read about this in  more detail in apple documents .

Comment: For background thread - we should always do Api calling or other handy calculation work in background thread so that our UI never freezes for Main Thread we should always DO UI related work in Main Thread.

Answer (score 1):

1.Why are they creating separate class for that cell.we can use the viewcontroller.m file to manage our cell in collection view.

Ans:Relating to real life, why we have separate rooms for study, drawing room, bedroom etc. Each and every thing has it's own scope. You can keep all your code in one file but for the shake of code reusability, moduled, in scope they have created seperated classes.

2.how ARC works (retain cycles, weak vs. strong, etc), threading (when to use background thread, when to use main).

Ans: Arc basically help automatically to manage memory.Thus saving development time. 
Retain Cycle: If two objects are holding each other strongly then none of them release to each other.Example:

Think about this setUp
You have a property as

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)AViewControllerObj *aViewControllerObj;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *nameString;
```

then somewhere in your code you write

```
aViewControllerObj.nameString = self.nameString;
```

`nameString` property in `aViewControllerObj` is also `strong`.

So here in this case you are creating two properties both with `strong`, so it will create a retain cycle.
To solve it change
`nameString` property in `aViewControllerObj` is to `weak`.

MainThread vs BackgroundThread:
Do all UIStuff in main thread.
You can schedule non-ui stuff in background thread.

You can see some of more helpful points here in my answer:
[helpful memory related points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655204/ios-application-behaviour-in-case-of-low-memory/20657274#20657274)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thnaks for your nice explantation too

Comment: i did but it not showing for me bez i am having no more point